# Object save in same value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am going to push object in an array using angularjs. But it stores same value in every object. Its an associate object.

```
service('setAttribs',function(){

 var setMapAttrib = {
  Processtet : {},
 };

 var tmp = [];

 return {

  setvalues : function(value){

   tmp.push(value);

   console.log(tmp);

   //setMapAttrib.Processtet[value.SelectedId] = { [value.getIndex] : value };
   //setMapAttrib.Processtet[value.SelectedId] = { [value.getIndex] : value };
   //console.log(setMapAttrib.Processtet[value.SelectedId]);

   /* if(setMapAttrib.Processtet[value.SelectedId]==null)
    setMapAttrib.Processtet[value.SelectedId] = [{}];

   setMapAttrib.Processtet[value.getIndex] = value;

   console.log(setMapAttrib.Processtet); */

  },
```

Anyone has an idea to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a working plnkr/fiddle for the same ?

Comment: Show how you use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to avoid pushing same scope object reference to array over and over

```
setvalues : function(value){
   var newItem = angular.copy(value);
   tmp.push(newItem );

   console.log(tmp);
```